# how ViewPager2 handle fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

In my app I have a ViewPager2, the fragment inside this ViewPager have some code on onViewCreated. I have 2 question:

1. If I update the dataset and then return to old one the onViewCreated is not called, because of fragment cache, how can I intercept the re-show? I am ok with cache, bui I want restore the initial focus of the fragment when re-showed.
2. <strike>How can I intercept the hiding from the fragment? My fragment show a dialog, then an external event can change the data set, I want in this case dismiss the dialog.</strike>

Are 2 days that I am trying to fix those 2 issues.

EDIT: I solved the 2 observing the changing of data set.

Answer (score 0):

Data sharing by ViewModel looks like a good solution for both cases. Fragments will rely on data change in shared ViewModel (depends on the structure of your screen it can be data sharing with host activity or parent fragment).
If it's not what you are looking for, provide more details.

Comment: I am already use the model view with live data, the problem is that I have an EditView outside the ViewPager and an EditView inside page, I added on onCreateView of the page a requestFocus, that is not called if page is from cache.

Comment: Have you tried to requestFocus in onStart/onResume f.e.?
As an option, you can listen which fragment become active and contact with it, but it's not an elegant solution.

Comment: I've tried onStart / onResume, neither is called.